# How to get a collection of divs with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the second img:

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <img src="1.jpg" >
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <img src="2.jpg" >
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <img src="3.jpg" >
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

I tried doing something like:

```
var imgSRC = $("div[id ='step']").get(1).find('img').attr('src'); 
alert(imgSRC);
```

Got nothing....

Comment: You're asking for `divs` with an `id` of `step` and your `fieldsets` (not `divs`) have a `class` of `step`

Comment: There are no `div` s in your code. `fieldset != div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
var imgSRC = $('#formElem').find('fieldset').eq(1).find('img').attr('src');
```

or...

```
var imgSRC = $('#formElem fieldset:eq(1) > img').attr('src');
```

While the former is more to type, it's **faster**. Since the latter invokes the **Sizzle** to query the element, it's less to type but also slower!

References: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: I'd suggest using `children('img')` rather than `find('img')` for performance reasons.

Comment: @Yads: afaik `.find()` has a better performance than `.children()`. That probably got optimized fixed in `1.5.0`, not tested that (yet).

Comment: @jAndy, impossible. find searches the entire DOM using Sizzle, children only searches direct children.

Comment: @Yads: `.find()` is still faster. See http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-vs-find. `.find()` will not crawl the entire DOM, only all descendents from the target node (recursivly). But for a lookup like this, its faster. Maybe different on nodes with more nested nodes tho.

Comment: @jAndy, wow, I take it back. I guess if you don't have many nodes under a parent find is faster than children. I wonder why everything you read says the opposite.